# Bottom bracket removal Falter 3 speed

Tags: bottom-bracket

I am having issues removing this bottom bracket from a vintage Falter 3 speed bike. For once crank arm removal was super easy, cotter pins came right off. However, struggling with this one. I imagine I need to remove cone but spindle keeps rotating. Perhaps using vise on opposite side
any advice more than welcome
thanks [image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the nut on the crank shaft?

Comment: All done, reinstalled the opposite crank arm which game me leverage and then unscrewed clockwise. Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Partly reinstall crank opposite nut.

Remove nut.

Update with new photos as necessary.